# Video calls in jailbroken iphone possible or not?

Tags: iphone, video, call

I want to develop an iphone app in which it is required to initiate video calling via 3g.Is it possible to initiate video calling programatically in iphone?The device can be jailbroken one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite possible to programmatically initiate video calling in iphone . Though in a jailbroken device im not so sure.

Comment: Can you give me an example code or some links that can help me? And Thanks for this quick response.